# what is the advantage of using the lambda function in python?

Tags: python, lambda

in python, we can directly evaluate the mathematical expression so why we are using the lambda function? and my question is that what is the advantage of using the lambda function in python.
for example:

if we want to evaluate the expression in python using without lambda function something like this -

```
a=10
b=20
c=a+b
print(c)
```

output:30

and if we want to evaluate the same expression in python using the lambda function something like this -

```
c=lambda a,b:a+b
print(c(10,20))
```

output:30

Please explain to me the advantage of using the lambda function in python.

Comment: lambda is a syntax. you're using it to sum numbers but you can do more complex things with lambda than simply adding numbers

Comment: that you don't need to declare them. They **don't** support  augmented assignment such as `lambda x: x+=1`

Comment: It's a feature that enables python to move towards functional programming. see the advantaged at https://realpython.com/python-functional-programming/

Comment: You can use it again?

Comment: In your example, there is no advantage.  It's primarily useful when you're calling a function that requires another function as an argument and it's easier to define one with a `lambda` than with a `def`.

Comment: you should not store them as callable variable but more in a `return` or as callback argument of other functions...

Comment: The primary use case is to define a function for use as a function argument or `dict` value, so that you don't need to come up with a name for the function. An attempt was once made to get rid of lambda expressions altogether in favor of special-purpose factories like `partial`, `itemgetter`, `attrgetter`, and `methodcaller`. The effort was abandoned, but the factories remained.

Comment: PEP-8 specifically comes out against using a lambda expression just to assign a value to a *name* (which is what a `def` statement already does).

Answer (score 1):

Lambda functions are very important in the context of functional programming, interacting mainly with interfaces such as `filter`, `map` and so forth.

Taking `map` as a canonical example, one of its arguments (the first one) is a function. In simple cases, when the function is not going to be reused, it is pretty practical to write

```
map(lambda x: ..., [...])
```

instead of its `def` counterpart

```
def f(x):
    ...
map(f, [...])
```

Comment: I wouldn't say *much* better. It's an option for very simple functions that won't otherwise be used again.

Comment: I'll also note that `map` and `filter` are inferior in every way (performance, readability) to equivalent listcomps and genexprs (also functional programming tools) if you need a `lambda` to make use of them. The only time they ever improve on listcomp/genexprs is if you already have an existing function (ideally a built-in) to use as the transform/predicate function. If you need a `lambda` to use `map`/`filter`, just don't; use the listcomp/genexpr.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I have solved this problems. Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

A lambda expression defines a function; the advantage over the `def` statement is you don't need to write a name for it.

A case of use is when you send a function as delegate and your function is so simple you don't need to code it as a `def` function:

```py
numbers = [1,2,3,4]

numbers.sort(key=lambda n: n % 10) # sort uses lambda function
```

Lambda expressions evaluate to a function; you can assign it to a variable, but [PEP8 recommends to use `def`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier:

```py
# Correct:
def f(x): return 2*x

# Wrong:
f = lambda x: 2*x
```